Resize table for listobject is not working
I need to resize a table with conditions:
if row header equals 1, then the table has to be resized up to that column.
My code's not working - there are no error messages, just nothing is happening.
I tried running code step by step, I don't get where the issue is.
Sub tablesize()

Dim ShMonth As Worksheet
Set ShMonth = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Month") 'sheet name

Dim colnum As Long
For colnum = 7 To 37 'column range name


Dim colindex As Long
colindex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, ShMonth.Rows(4), 0) 'lookup for column index that equals 1


    Dim qnum As Long
    For qnum = 1 To 1 
        Dim table As ListObject
        Set table = ShMonth.ListObjects(qnum) 'query table
        

    If ShMonth.Cells(4, colnum).Value = colindex Then
        table.Resize table.Range(Cells(19, 6), Cells(48, colindex))
     
    End If
    
Next qnum
Next colnum

End Sub


If nothing is happening, then ShMonth.Cells(4, colnum).Value = colindex is False.

Btw, why do you have the For qnum = 1 To 1 loop? If you only have one table, there's no need for a loop.

I have several tables in the real worksheet, but I'm testing code in a draft with just one to minimize the amount of potential errors that are probably ruining the code

The first problem that I see is that your logic is probably flawed.
You write
colindex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, ShMonth.Rows(4), 0) 

With that you will get the column number where (in the row 4) you find the value 1. Lets say this returns the value 10 - with other words, you find the 1 in cell J4.
Now you loop from column 7 to column 37 and compare the values in row 4 with the value of colindex (=10). If you would find a 10 in row 4, you would try to adjust the table range until that column. I strongly assume that you don't have such a value in row 4 - and that this is not what you mean at all.
Basically, you don't need to loop over all the columns, you know already that you want to limit the data until column 10.
Now I am not 100% sure about your Resize-command, but I assume that it will fail. I would recommend to use an intermediate variable to calculate the new Range and pass this to the Resize. If something fails, you can easily check with the debugger if that Range was set correctly.
Dim table As ListObject
Set table = ShMonth.ListObjects(1)
Dim colindex As Long
On Error Resume Next
colindex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, ShMonth.Rows(4), 0) 'lookup for column index that equals 1
On Error GoTo 0
If colindex = 0 Then 
    MsgBox "No column found with value 1"
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim newRange As Range
Set newRange = table.Range
' Resize the range so that it contains all columns until the found column.
Set newRange = newRange.Resize(, colindex - newRange.Column + 1)
Debug.Print newRange.Address
table.Resize newRange


Hi FunThomas, thank you for the revised version of the code, the last bit helped a lot!
